# To create acoustic model from scratch or to adapt existing acoustic model

Tags: speech-recognition, cmusphinx, pocketsphinx

While trying to implement speech recognition system for 1 particular speaker with mixing russian and arabic speech I'm facing some problems.
When adapting acoustic model with 15 minutes of speech of speaker, there is too high percentage of errors (it recognize right 1 from 6-10 words).
What I've did: 
 1. I've transcribed arabic words to russian language and put them into
    dictionary.
 2. I've tried old model msu_ru_zero.cd_cont_2000 from ru4sphinx project
    and new one from cmusphinx-ru-5.2 (latest acoustic model for russian
    language at this moment).
 3. I've used dictionary and language model made by me from texts of my field of study. There is almost 200MB of text in utf-8 in russian. But only small part of the arabic terms were in this dictionary.

There are only few (4 from 40) audio tracks for adaptation failed with " align audio to transcript", other goes through without errors.
Also in report after bw command usage there are 220 senones that are not in adaptation audio tracks.

How could I decrease errors' rate for this mixing langauge?
Or I need to create acoustic model for this 1 speaker from scratch?
I don't need to transcribe arabic at all, just russian, if arabic will default to some common term (like -unk-) it will be good too.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the issue with my dictionary.
it was because of 
`text2wfreq <lmbase.txt | wfreq2vocab`
command.
before I've used `wfreq2vocab` with default parameters, so my dictionary was truncated to most frequent 20,000 words. In my starting vocabulary there are more than 200K words. `wfreq2vocab` has `-top` argument, so -top 400000 works for me (it doesn't filter words, it just creates vocabulary now)

And second - now I'm using MAP adaptation instead of mllr.

with 30 minutes of adaptation audio it shows me 50-75 percent of correct words.